# Codeigniter - How can I initiate the download of a file and reset the form to be used again

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Using Codeigniter, I'm trying to do something basic.

The site has a form where users upload files for processing.  After the files are processed, new files are created and saved in a zip file. Then I use $this->zip->download() to start the download.

But after that I can't do anything to refresh the upload form.  And if I reload the view first, the download doesn't work.

All I want to do is upload the files, create the zip, download the zip and wind up with a clean upload form.

Any suggestions how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to do it on the same page because of missmatched headers. You could try the following: when the zip is ready save it and name it some random/unique id/md5 anything and print the download link in the view with "click here to download your file" with target="_blank" param so it opens in a new tab. (usually browsers are smart enough that it will auto close it when you accept the file). And so you can reset the form in the view as well.
Another way could be with ajax and js i guess but that would be much longer to write.

Ps.: just dont forget to delete the files after x amount of time (if you dont need them)

Comment: Thanks!  I wish there was a better helper for this situation, but I guess it's a little more involved than it seems.  Thanks again